# How can VLAN clients access the internet via a VLAN gateway and an ISP router?

Tags: routing, vlan

I've got a small network which I've split up into 3 VLANs :

- 192.168.0.1/24 : the "default" VLAN
- 192.168.2.1/24 : VLAN 2
- 192.168.3.1/24 : VLAN 3

I've got a VLAN capable switch, and I'm using a Raspberry PI with Ubuntu 18.04 as a DHCP server on VLAN 2 and 3 (DHCP on the default VLAN is handled by the ISP router).

The Raspberry PI is connected to the physical port 1 on the switch, and that port is set up as a trunk port. When I connect a computer to one of the other ports that participates in VLAN 2 or 3, I get an IP address assigned for the correct VLAN - so everything works well for that part. I'm using virtual interfaces on the Raspberry PI to handle the VLANs (`eth0.2` and `eth0.3`).

The `eth0` interface receives an IP address from the DHCP server running on the ISP router, and the default gateway on that default VLAN is 192.168.0.1.

I'd like to be able to connect to the internet from VLAN 2 and 3. The default gateway for both VLANs is the Raspberry PI. For VLAN 2 the IP is 192.168.2.1 and for VLAN 3 the IP is 192.168.3.1.

On the Raspberry PI, how do I route incoming traffic from VLAN 2 (`eth0.2`) onto `eth0`, and how do I ensure that the routed traffic goes via 192.168.0.1 and onto the internet?

[image]

Comment: Well in a nutshell: As long as you have IP forwarding enabled on the Raspberry, then any clients VLAN 2 and 3 will be able to connect to the Internet using the Raspberry as their default gateway. The Raspberry in turn need your router as its default gateway. It can be done with things like `ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via <insert ISP router ip> dev eth0`. Mind you: This has to be the last entry in your routing table since it literary matches all IP packages.

Comment: Also if the ISP router cannot be configured to be aware of 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 routes through the rPI then NAT has to be done by the rPI (so clients will be nat-ed twice: once by the rPI, once by the ISP router).

Comment: The router can not be configured to be aware of the VLANs, it's a very basic ISP router. Will I need to set up MASQUERADE rules in iptables on the rPI for this to happen @A.B?

Comment: You could actually use (almost) the whole 192.168.0/24 range to SNAT clients into rather than just the rPI's IP, but this would be more difficult to setup. So yes use MASQUERADE.

Comment: and to be clear: there's no vlan involved anymore here. only routing. the ISP router must know (or can't be configured to know) *routes* not *vlans*.

Comment: @A.B yes, agreed. When traffic leaves goes onto eth0 no more VLAN should be involved.